# How to increase performance for linked server to ms-Access?

Tags: sql-server, performance, ms-access, oledb, linked-server

how to make better performence for sql server linked server to ms access database?

a select query takes longer then sql equal table and original query in ms-access.

the query does not cache so its about the same time after running many times.

**profiler**:

linked server: 2 reads, 1079 CPU, 2584 duration.

sql table:   5956 reads, 32 CPU, 1379 duration.

**why there is so little reads?, more CPU?**

**execution Plan**:

linkedSserver:

```
<Statements>
            <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" **StatementEstRows**="10000" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="120" StatementSubTreeCost="3.36333" StatementText="select X from XXX" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x866F5A3CDCB9B9E0" QueryPlanHash="0x8FFAA09874A2CFDF" RetrievedFromCache="true">
              <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
              <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" NonParallelPlanReason="NoParallelPlansInDesktopOrExpressEdition" CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="115" CompileCPU="105" CompileMemory="112">
                <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
                <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="838814" EstimatedPagesCached="52425" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="1" />
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="3.36333" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" **EstimateRows**="10000" LogicalOp="Remote Scan" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Remote Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="3.36333">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Server="[MyLinkedServer]" Table="[XXX]" Column="X" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" **ActualRows**="100000" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <RemoteScan RemoteSource="MyPath\Ari1.Mdb" RemoteObject="XXX" />
                </RelOp>
              </QueryPlan>
            </StmtSimple>
          </Statements>
```

sql table:

```
  <Statements>
    <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" **StatementEstRows**="100000" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="120" StatementSubTreeCost="4.52143" StatementText="select X from XXX" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0xFF5860851E080CA1" QueryPlanHash="0xAC44A8F064D60D2E" RetrievedFromCache="true">
      <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
      <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" NonParallelPlanReason="NoParallelPlansInDesktopOrExpressEdition" CachedPlanSize="16" CompileTime="0" CompileCPU="0" CompileMemory="104">
        <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
        <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="838814" EstimatedPagesCached="52425" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="1" />
        <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.110079" EstimateIO="4.41135" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" **EstimateRows**="100000" LogicalOp="Table Scan" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="4.52143" TableCardinality="100000">
          <OutputList>
            <ColumnReference Database="[DBName]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[XXX]" Column="X" />
          </OutputList>
          <RunTimeInformation>
            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" **ActualRows**="100000" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
          </RunTimeInformation>
          <TableScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
            <DefinedValues>
              <DefinedValue>
                <ColumnReference Database="[DBName]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[XXX]" Column="X" />
              </DefinedValue>
            </DefinedValues>
            <Object Database="[DBName]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[XXX]" IndexKind="Heap" Storage="RowStore" />
          </TableScan>
        </RelOp>
      </QueryPlan>
    </StmtSimple>
  </Statements>
```

**why Estimated values are constant?**

Comment: if you are migrating the MS Access to SQL use "SSMA for Access" software by Microsoft. Please read below 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/what-s-new-in-ssma-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes, querying a table in a linked server via an OLE DB provider like Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 could very well be slower than querying an equivalent table that is local to the SQL Server instance. So what is your question?

Comment: migrating was not the rigt word, the ms access database must stay becouse it is used by other software, but other data is in sql, so we decided using linked server and synonyms.

Comment: what can i do to make it faster? maybe diffrent linkedserver or provider configuration, or allowing access to cache, more reads? diffrent syntax? or any ideas